# How to predict values based on a logistic equation in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, classification, generalized-linear-model

If a logistic equation has already been given in the form of: 
$$
Y = \frac{1}{1+e^{-(a+\sum_k b_kx_k)}}
$$
How can I use this equation as a predictor to predict the class labels (binary) of data points in the test set?

Is there any way to create a `glm` object based on an equation instead of giving a training set, and then use the `predict()` function in R to do a prediction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a more deeper research, I found a solution(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112860/manually-build-logistic-regression-model-for-prediction-in-r) provided by @MrFlick that works perfect in this situation.